# How to add space to array?

Tags: arrays

Is there any way to add a small vertical space to this array so that the transpose in b does not touch the array line?

```
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{c|c}
    z       & X \\
    \hline 
    \,      & b^T
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is appropriate determine `\extrarowheight`. For example:

```
\documentclass[{12pt}]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{c|c}
    z       & X \\
    \hline
    \,      & b^T
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or instead `array` use `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[{12pt}]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{tblr}{c|c}
    z       & X \\
    \hline
    \,      & b^T
  \end{tblr}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]